# key error in dictionary even though that key is present

Tags: python, dictionary, data-manipulation

what I am working on is chaining dictionaries. So I already chained two but when I try to chain it , the code throws an key error. This the function I build to convert csv file to a dictionary.

```
def csv_read_to_dict(fl_name):
    file = open(fl_name,"r")
    data = csv.reader(file)
    data_list = list(data)
    
    final_list = []
    for value in range(1,len(data_list)):
        final_list.append(data_list[value])
        

    final_dict = {}
    for data in final_list:
        final_dict[data[0]] = {"SEM_4":{"Subject":{"OS":data[2],"OOP":data[3],"COA":data[4],"DM":data[5],"Management":data[6]}}}
    return final_dict
```

what I was expecting is add sem 3 and 4 result to the existing dictionary..[this image shows sem 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buqjj.png)

Comment: You open the file, but do not close it. Better use `with open(fl_name) as ... :` that will close the file for you.

Comment: I think you would have a better chance of getting help if you edited the question and included a sample file, or posted some sample content that might be in the file so it is possible to test the code.

Answer (score 0):

The update() function in Python can be used to link dictionaries. However, based on the function you gave, it appears like you are creating a new dictionary for each row in the CSV file rather than immediately updating an existing dictionary. To solve this circumstance, you must first determine whether the key (for example, "SEM_4") already exists in the existing dictionary. If it does, you can change the value; otherwise, you can create a new key-value pair.

Here is a revised version of your function that includes semesters 3 and 4, with the results chained:

```
def csv_read_to_dict(fl_name, existing_dict=None):
    file = open(fl_name, "r")
    data = csv.reader(file)
    data_list = list(data)

    final_list = []
    for value in range(1, len(data_list)):
        final_list.append(data_list[value])

    if existing_dict is None:
        final_dict = {}
    else:
        final_dict = existing_dict

    for data in final_list:
        student_id = data[0]
        sem_4_data = {
            "SEM_4": {
                "Subject": {
                    "OS": data[2],
                    "OOP": data[3],
                    "COA": data[4],
                    "DM": data[5],
                    "Management": data[6]
                }
            }
        }

        if student_id in final_dict:
            if "SEM_4" in final_dict[student_id]:
                final_dict[student_id]["SEM_4"]["Subject"].update(sem_4_data["SEM_4"]["Subject"])
            else:
                final_dict[student_id].update(sem_4_data)
        else:
            final_dict[student_id] = sem_4_data

    return final_dict
```

You can now send an existing dictionary (including data for semesters 1 and 2) as the 'existing_dict' parameter to this updated function, and it will integrate the data for semesters 3 and 4 into the existing dictionary. If you don't have an existing dictionary, run the function without the 'existing_dict' option and it will generate a new dictionary with the data from semesters 3 and 4.

Thank you very much.